# What is the Python function for searching through a data frame for items in a list and returning a dummy variable?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Essentially I have created a list of words ("man," "guy," etc.) that I've titled 'Male' and I want to search through my data frame for words within this list and then return a value of 1 if present.

Thus far I have tried the pd.get_dummies function in pandas but it's not doing exactly what I need it to and I'm not sure what specific functions I need to be searching for on the web. (I'm just now teaching myself Python so I'm super novice - please help!)

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: dummy = pd.get_dummies(bios['description'])
bios = pd.concat([bios,dummy],axis=1)
bios.head()
bios = bios.merge(dummy,left_index=True,right_index=True)
bios.head()

Comment: 'description' being my column header I'm looking at and 'bios' being my cleaned data frame

Comment: Please edit this code into your question using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59023464/edit)!

Answer (score 0):

I've interpreted your question as: return a 1 where the dataframe entry is in my list of words ("Males"). Let me know if this isn't what you were thinking.

You can simply check that each entry is in your list of words. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

male_matches = ['man', 'guy', 'dude']

# Create a dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Nickname'])
df.Nickname = ['man', 'guy', 'man', 'chick', 'dude', 'gal', 'woman']

# This line checks for matches
# conversion to an *int* makes the variable 1 (if true) and 0 (if false)
df['Match'] = [int(i in male_matches) for i in df.Nickname]
```

The dataframe is now:

```
  Nickname  Match
0      man      1
1      guy      1
2      man      1
3    chick      0
4     dude      1
5      gal      0
6    woman      0
```

For future reference, it's worth putting what you have tried so far in your questions as it shows everyone that (a) you have actually tried, and (b) saves time by not suggesting things that you have already done. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you so much!! (also, great tip - I appreciate it)